# Access is denied while register provider (wevtutil)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, etw

I´m trying to register a manifest based provider using wevtutil and get the following error:

```
**** Warning: Publisher ExampleProvider resources are not accessible.
```

So I run wevtutil gp ExampleProvider and get the following message:

```
Failed to open metadata for publisher ExampleProvider. Access is denied
```

The user account I´m working with have `Administrator` privilage and is part of the groups `Event Log Readers`, `Performance Log Users`, and `Performance Monitor Users`.

The manifest file is the same as in this [example](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/roadan/2011/02/13/creating-and-publishing-events-using-etw-manifest-based-provider/).

Does anyone know whats wrong?

A side note is that my project folder has read-only flag under properties and when I try to change it does not complain. However, when I open up the properties again it remains read-only.. Can anyone explain that behaviour?

**EDIT**
I have located the problem area and it is the channel.

In the example manifest created in the [tutorial](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/roadan/2011/02/13/creating-and-publishing-events-using-etw-manifest-based-provider/) they create a channel like:

```
<channels>
    <channel name="MyChannel" chid="MyChannel" symbol="MyChannel" type="Debug" enabled="true" message="$(string.ExampleProvider.channel.MyChannel.message)">
    </channel>
    <importChannel name="Application" chid="appchnl">
    </importChannel>
</channels>
```

And when I remove this channel and use default in the event I get no warnings, do I not have access to write events to that channel or something (Application)?

Comment: And you run the command prompt from where you enter the wevtutil commands specifically as administrator? Even administrators do not run all programs with elevated rights.

Comment: Yes I do. How do I give administrators full access?

Comment: right click on the link and choose 'run as administrator'

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token

Comment: I´m running the console as administrator and then the application from that console, does that not yield the same result?

Comment: what is the command that you try to run?

Comment: wevtutil im MyManifest.man

Comment: I tested it yesterday and it works fine for me. Do you have a AV suite running which may block it?

Comment: See edit, I have located the issue

Comment: if you don't want to use ETW to write to the Eventlog you can emove this channel data.

Comment: But I want to write to the EventLog..