# ERROR_EVT_EVENT_TEMPLATE_NOT_FOUND with Windows EWT

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, etw

I am attempting to print a very simple log to Windows event viewer. When I call `EventWrite()` in my .cpp file, I get error code 15003 `ERROR_EVT_EVENT_TEMPLATE_NOT_FOUND` in the event viewer and my message is not displayed. I think the problem that I am having is that the `.rc` file that is generated when I compile my manifest is not being compiled along with the project even though I have dragged it into the resource folder in the solution explorer.

When I registered my manifest with `wevtutil.exe` I get the following warning: `Publisher ExampleProvider resources are not accessible`.When I ask for details on this error, I receive this output: `Failed to open metadata for publisher ExampleProvider. Access is denied`.

I have already looked at [Access is denied while register provider (wevtutil)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525941/access-is-denied-while-register-provider-wevtutil) and it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it was a permission issue just like in [Access is denied while register provider (wevtutil)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525941/access-is-denied-while-register-provider-wevtutil). I corrected this by placing my project at the root of my C drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily verify whether your `.rc` file is compiled correctly into your project by opening your compiled `.dll` or `.exe` file in Visual Studio. Go to `File->Open->File` and open your executable or library. Now check whether you can see the compiled ETW resource file. In my project it is in the folder "WEVT_TEMPLATE". If you do not see it in your binary, then you likely have not compiled it into your binary. To do this, add your `.rc` to your project (Choose add resource).

A sidenote: Please also verify that the ResourceFileName and messageFileName in your Manifest file point correctly to your lib or executable.

After running the registration command in a command prompt.

`wevtutil im yourProvider.man`

You can inspect your provider registration as well as possible errors by running the following command afterwards:

`wevtutil gp yourProvider`

Hope that helps.